# How to determine if any field in a model / nested model changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there some quick way to find out if any of a model's fields or any fields of it's nested models (a.k.a. associations) changed?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To see if a ActiveRecord object has changed, you can call:

```
instance.changed?
```

To see if a specific attribute was changed, you can do:

```
instance.attr_changed?
```

where attr is the attribute you want to check.

To check for if a nested model changed, you can just do:

```
instance.nested_model.changed?
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies! But is there any way to check if any nested model's attributes have changed without knowing in advance what nested models a model has?

Comment: I would check Rails Observers: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html which could potentially notify the parent model of the change.

Comment: I don't think nested_model (association) changes are tracked https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/541-dirty-attributes-with-associations

Comment: Does the flag still trigger on the `updated_at` column? Just curious because after you save doesn't that column update to the current date on `instance.save` regardless of whether anything changed, and therefore gets marked as changed?

Comment: i get "undefined method `changed?' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xfa07b3f> when i do @message.groups.changed? in rails 3.2.14

Comment: I got the same result @SanoJ when I am trying to get all the changed attributes in a nested model.

Comment: @SanoJ I know it is an old post, but answering so that it helps someone in future. Since, groups is a `has_many` relation it will be an array and you will have to do: `@message.groups.any? { |g| g.changed? }` or `@message.groups.any?(&:changed?)` to check any of the groups associated was changed. For `has_one` and `belongs_to` do as the post says.

Comment: update on @rubyprince comment, `changed?` isn't working in my 5.2 app, now working with `@message.groups.any?(&:saved_changes)` , this is if using `has_many'

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old question but recently came across same situation.

You can get all changes for your nested model using `previous_changes` method even after saving the object.

```
parent_model_object.nested_model_name.previous_changes
```

This will list all changes in the nested model along with old and new value.

Comment: user.posts.previous_changes is this correct syntax?

Answer (score 8):

with 5.1 + the following works for me:

`saved_changes?` will let you know if your object has changed:

```
my_object.saved_changes?
=> true
```

`saved_changes` will let you know which fields changed, the before value and the after value for each field:

```
my_object.saved_changes
=> {"first_name"=>['Jim', 'Jimmy'], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 06 Dec 2018 18:45:00 UTC +00:00, Thu, 06 Dec 2018 18:52:44 UTC +00:00]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can determine if an object has changed but not yet been saved by calling:

```
my_object.changed?
```

You can also determine if individual attributes have changed (say you have a `first_name` attribute):

```
my_object.first_name_changed?
```

As far as nested models go, I think you'd have to call `changed?` on them each individually.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! But is there any way to check if any nested model's attributes have changed without knowing in advance what nested models a model has?

Comment: I don't think so. There's probably a way to get a list of all associated models, but I don't know it off the top of my head. As Mike mentioned above, Observers may be useful. May I ask what you're trying to achieve with all this though, as there may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you can do `model.things.detect { |thing| thing.id.blank? }`