# How to check whether an instance of an ActiveRecord model is up to date?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

For testing reasons, I want to check that one of my methods doesn't update a specific entry in my database. Is there a simple way to ask an instance of an ActiveRecord model if its in sync with the database? for instance, if we had a method foobar? that could do this:

```
old_post = Post.find(1)
updated_post = Post.find(1)
updated_post.update_attributes(name: "this is a new name not like the old name")

old_post.foobar? #should return true, as its attributes are no longer up to date
updated_post.foobar? #should return false, as its attributes match the database directly
```

So is there a method that acts like foobar, or something like it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if any field in a model / nested model changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615594/how-to-determine-if-any-field-in-a-model-nested-model-changed)

Comment: @depa: nope, it's not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @depa, the ActiveRecord::Dirty module determines if the instance includes changes that haven't been saved to the database. I want to know if the database includes changes that aren't reflected in the ActiveRecord instance.

Comment: Oh, right. Terribly sorry. I retracted the close vote.

Comment: why don't you use the return value of update_attributes method?

Comment: Have you got timestamps?  If so...
def changed?(object)
 test_object = object.class.find(object.id)
 ! (object.updated_at == test_object.updated_at)
end

Comment: well, that didn't format well... :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies beyond finding a method which tells you wether an attribute has been updated, but in the relationship among the different objects that are instantiated. First it is important to understand, that `old_post` and `updated_post` are *unrelated* ruby objects. They know about how to save *their own* state to the database, but they do not know about each other.

Therefore your first requirement for `foobar?` cannot be fulfilled, as `old_post` will think it is up-to-date as long as no attribute has been updated. In contrast the `changed?` method will roughly answer in the way you are trying to achieve for `updated_post`. However it does so because it *thinks* nothing has happened since it was last saved, this will not be verified against the database upon each call of `changed?` as this would be wasting a database call in 99.9% of all cases.

This means it is all too easy to generate anomalies between the objects you created as there is no direct connection between the two (except the *implicit* connection that they once represented the same database row). If you change an attribute in one object (using e.g. `title='?'` it will change the value of the object and take note of the change in the `changed`-array. Once you save this object it will save its *changed* attributes to the database (by creating an individually constructed `update`-statement).

Another object *that is already instantiated* (as `old_post` in your example) will *not* know about this change and might change other attributes if you are not careful (or even the same ones *if they have been changed again*). Depending on your database adapter you may try to use the `lock!` method which *will* synchronize your object with the database before allowing any modifications. This however will not happen automatically as in most controller methods updates do not conflict nearly often enough to merit the synchronization as it will be idempotent in most cases.

This does not go without saying that rails can not save you from thinking about your transaction semantics if you want to guarantee specific ACID semantics for your controller methods.