# How to check hstore key changes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have hstore column (email_subscribing) in model.
And have strore_accessor

I want to check changes of one key from this store on after_update callback

```js
store_accessor :email_subscribing, :common_users_list, :admins_list, :caretakers_list,                      :tenant_admins_list, :managers_list

after_update :update_mailchimp_subscriptions, if: :email_ep_updates_changed?
```

But get an error - undefined method `email_ep_updates_changed?'

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer that you're looking for can be found here in this previous post:

[How to determine if any field in a model / nested model changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615594/how-to-determine-if-any-field-in-a-model-nested-model-changed)

The method name  `email_ep_updates_changed?` doesn't appear to exist but you should be able to accomplish what you're setting out to do via the post above. You just need to add the `_changed?` to the end of the attribute name of what it is that you're checking or use `.changed?` on the actual Model itself if you're not looking for a specific attribute.